# Anagularjs ngTagsInput create a new tag

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am using Angularjs ngTagsInput for Tags. I am also using auto complete option.
If a particular tag is not there, Say for example user enters "Tag", And Tag is not available, How can i customize and ask the user create Tag?

Comment: Why can't the user create the tag inline? I mean, by typing "tag" and pressing enter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Micheal! When user enters new tag, i want to provide the option "create Tag", by clicking on create tag user should be able to create new tag.

Comment: A tags input control expects the user to create a new tag by typing some text and pressing some hotkey. I don't think that adding an extra step is very UX friendly.